# calculating surface area of an arbitrary portion of a hypersphere

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area, polar-coordinates

This is coming from a statistics background.  I have several distributions defined on the hypersphere (really, the positive orthant of the hypersphere).  I'm trying to compare these candidate distributions against the original data I used to fit the distribution.

For this, I'm intending to use something like Hellinger distance.  I can calculate the probability of falling into a particular area numerically--using the posterior predictive and empirical, I just compute the number that fell into a said area and divide by total sample size.  But for Hellinger distance, I still need the area that I'm integrating across--that means the surface area of an arbitrary subset of the hypersphere.

This $n$-dimensional geometry is somewhat outside my current understanding.  Is there any established method for calculating surface area of an arbitrary portion of the hypersphere?

Comment: Area of an arbitrary set is an arbitrary number. How do you ***define*** your small sections in the first place?

Comment: @IvanNeretin in some appropriate coordinate system, changing some dimensions by some small amount.

Comment: Then the area will be some small number. See, it is not going to be more specific than that until _you_ get more specific.

Answer (score 0):

All very well understood:

$$ S_n = \frac{2^{(n+1)/2} \pi^{(n-1)/2)}}{(n-2)!!} $$

for $n$ odd;

$$S_n = \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{(n/2 -1)!}$$

for $n$ even.

And the area of the positive orthant is a trivial fraction of this.

(Computer that orthant area as a proportion for $n = 2,3,4...$ and see if you see the rather obvious rule.)

Comment: As far as I understand, that's the surface area of the complete hypersphere.  I'm trying to find the surface area of an arbitrary portion of the hypersphere.   That is, I'm trying to partition the positive orthant of the hypersphere into small sections, calculate probability of falling into that section under the empirical distribution and under my candidate distribution, square the difference and multiply it by the the proportion of the positive orthant of the hypersphere that *that* section covers.